# How Hibernate process '?'

Tags: java, sql, hibernate

I'm new in Hibernate. I can't understand how Hibernate process **?** in `Restrictions.sqlRestriction()` method. For example, there is a sample from official [guide](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/reference/en/html/querycriteria.html):

```
List cats = sess.createCriteria(Cat.class)
    .add( Restrictions.sqlRestriction("lower({alias}.name) like lower(?)", "Fritz%", Hibernate.STRING) )
    .list();
```

Looks like it is a placeholder. Will Hibernate convert this statement in `...like lower(Fritz%)` SQL request?

If yes, then `lower(Fritz%)` doesn't looks valid, correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, **?** is a placeholder that is filled with "Fritz%".

**%** it's a wildcard, and it is often used with `like` like in this case.
Basically the query search for every Cat whose name start with "Fritz".

**EDIT**
I didn't get what was your concern with `lower(Fritz%)` at first, but as XtremeBaumer suggested, the query is actually converted to `lower('Fritz%')`

Comment: It is converted to `lower('Fritz%')`. You are missing the `'` signs

Comment: then SQL statement `... like lower('Fritz%')` searches for every Cat whose name starts with "Fritz" and converts it into lower-case, right?

Comment: The other way: the ```lower``` (in both case) is applied before the ```like```, so the query is actually case insensitive. The query is going to match all the cats whose name start with "felix", "Felix", "FeLiX", etc.

Comment: @Kaiak – You surely mean "fritz", "FrItZ", "FRITZ", … and not "Felix", right?

Comment: @tquadrat yes of course, sorry!

Comment: @XtremeBaumer In most SQL implementations it will not convert to `lower('Fritz%')`, the statement is prepared with a parameter, and on execute, a value is sent to the server for that parameter. The value is usually not inlined into the query string.